# How to solve inconsistent visual studio indentation error?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual studio new line indents inconsistently sometimes.
Below is the phenomenon.

[image: indentation]

Anyone know how to solve this?
I'm using visual studio 2022 community.

Comment: If you turn on view white space (tools → options → Text Editor → General → View Whitespace), what does it look like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Timothy G. The line has no whitespace arrow and its cursor position lies at the position of image I attached.